# implicit operator causing ambiguous method signature resolution

Tags: c#, implicit-conversion, ambiguous-call

I have the following two methods that both create me a couple of `Constraint<T>` instances. The first creates types of `Constraint<Quantity>` and the second creates types of `Constraint<IParameter<Quantity>>`:

```
public void ConstrainBetween(Quantity min, Quantity max)
{
  .. 
}

public void ConstrainBetween(IParameter<Quantity> min, IParameter<Quantity> max)
{
  .. 
}
```

The argument types `Quantity` and `IParameter<T>` are like this:

```
public class Quantity
{
  double Value;
  .. 
}

public class IParameter<T> 
{
  T Value;
  Func<T> Formula;
  .. 
}
```

It all has worked nicely for months until i overloaded the implicit operator for IParameter as follows :

```
public class IParameter<T>
{
     public T Value;
     public Func<T> Formula;
  

     public static implicit operator T(IParameter<T> p)
     {
         return p.Value; 
     }
}
```

Now the following usage no longer compiles:

```
HydrModel.TopWaterLevel5yr.ConstrainBetween(OutletPipe.IL, Transform.Z);
HydrModel.TopWaterLevel30yr.ConstrainBetween(OutletPipe.IL, Transform.Z);
```

Error:

> The call is ambiguous between the following methods or properties: 'QuantityInput.ConstrainBetween(Quantity, Quantity)' and 'QuantityInput.ConstrainBetween(IParameter, IParameter)'

I understand that the compiler implicitly converts `IParameter<Quantity>` to `Quantity` making both method signatures potential targets and I know that I can resolve the ambiguity problem by:

1. not overloading the implicit operator
2. using an explicit operator overload instead
3. using two different method names

I don't want to to 1 or 2 because the benefits elsewhere of implicit overloading outweigh this drawback.

I am currently intending to take strategy (3) and work with different signature names.

I post this question just in case there is an alternative approach that would allow me to have my cake and eat it?  For example is there some way to specify exactly the method signature in the call to invoke it?

## EDIT

Someone asked why do i need both methods - why not just get rid of the second one since the implicit overload will ensure calling of the first?
The reason is that calling `Constraint<Quantity>.Value` always returns the same Quantity whereas calling `Constraint<IParameter<Quantity>>.Value` returns a different Quantity at different times according to its Formula property.  Therefore I do need a strategy for creating a Constraint where T can be either `Quantity` or `IParameter<Quantity>`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If your `IParameter<Quantity>` is properly designed to be implicitly cast to `Quantity`, then you shouldn't have any need in the second method ConstrainBetween. The `IParameter` also seems to be just a simple DTO, carrying a single value, and not anything else.

So, my solution would be to get rid of `public void ConstrainBetween(IParameter<Quantity> min, IParameter<Quantity> max)` entirely and focus on the value in the first method, rather than on the value's carrying type.

### Update

Since @MonkeyFace has edited his post, I would also like to add some thoughts.

It seems that now `IParameter<T>` doesn't carry a single value anymore, but two or more values. The difference described in the updated question between the two methods also indicates that `IPerameter<T>` is not an equivalent to its `T` value.

From this perspective it now seems odd to have an `implicit` operator, because **(a)** it loses that additional info (since losing information should only be done so deliberately - in my opinion) and **(b)** the two types are not equivalent to each other.

So the new proposed change would be to **migrate from implicit operattor to explicit one**.

I see your comment that "there are drawbacks of using explicit operatior", but I imagine those drawbacks being having to use `(T)` in those scenarios where the cast should occur, and I consider those cases the lesser evil.

Comment: sorry i completely understand the confusion so I'll edit my post to try to explain.  Thank you for reading and replying to my question.

Comment: @MonkeyFace ok I've updated my post.

Comment: thanks - i'm going to mark your reply as the ideal answer even though I'm not actually (at this time) going to do that for reasons that are esoteric to the project but in principle i do agree with you for 90% cases.

Answer (score 0):

I seem to have answered my own question by changing the second signature from this:

```
public void ConstrainBetween(IParameter<Quantity> min, IParameter<Quantity> max)
{
}
```

to this:

```
public void ConstrainBetween<T>(T min, T max) where T : IParameter<Quantity>
{
}
```

which i guess is now allowing the compiler to find a method marked as having the matching type prior to implicit conversion.  ...At any rate the project now compiles.

Although this is the solution I have opted for on this specific project *in general* I would agree with the marked solution for 90% of my projects.